# How to display paragraph under h1 tag in CSS Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am doing a typewriter effect where my name gets typed out, and the only thing that works to keep it centered is `justify-content: center`. The only thing is, I cannot put a paragraph underneath the flex item, and paragraph acts like it isn't there and nothing seems to work. I have tried `top: 315px;` but it doesn't work.

```css
  body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  animation: type 1s steps(22), blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  width: 14ch;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(2);
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
  100% {
    width: 15ch;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: black;
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
  #welcome {
    position: relative;
    top: 315px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hi, I'm Winston</h1>
  <p id="welcome">text</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to remove position absolute and add a flex-direction which in your case is `column`

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
  animation: type 1s steps(22),
    blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  width: 14ch;
  transform:translateY(-50%)  scale(2);
}
@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
  100% {
    width: 15ch;
  }
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor{
  from{
    border-right-color:black;
  }
  to{
    border-right-color:transparent;
  }
  #welcome {
    position: relative;
    top: 315px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hi, I'm Winston</h1>
  <p id="welcome">text</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I have another question. I can't seem to change the font-size of the p tag. I added `font size: 40px;` but it doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: Try doing `#id { font-size: 40px}` or if you want all p-tags to have this attribute do `p { font-size: 40px}` if both those don't work check for any JavaScript that may be altering the styling and remove said JavaScript or change it to add a font-size of 40px. Let me know if this works, if the answer helped you please click the checkmark on the left : )

Comment: Didn't work. But thank you though for helping me position the p element.

Comment: Np, another way you could try and debug this is by opening developer tools and clicking on said p tag and seeing what is altering the css styling

Comment: I'm going to ask another question about this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css.

```
#welcome{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Final CSS.

```
  body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  animation: type 1s steps(22), blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  width: 14ch;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(2);
}
#welcome{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
  100% {
    width: 15ch;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: black;
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```